# PhpStorm 9 can not detect XAMPP interpreter

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, interpreter

I don't remember exactly what I've done but my PhpStorm seem like can not detect PHP interpreter from XAMPP any more. So when I write html code on the PhpStorm editor, it's always warning that "element html (or all another tag) must be declared", and that tag color red.

I try jump to `File / Setting / Languages & Frameworks / PHP` to reset PHP interpreter to `php.exe` in my `c:\xampp\php` directory, but the result PhpStorm warning is:

> PHP-version: Not installed, Debugger: Not installed.

I also try configure the remote interpreter but it's so complicated for me because I do not have experience with vagrant/virtual machine.

After that I decide download another PHP interpreter from php.net but I can not find any php.exe. It just c file.

So what can I do to solve the problem. I think the problem is my `php.exe` become wrong because when I download the trial PhpStorm 10 the problem still remains.

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: *"So when I write html code on the PhpStorm editor, it's always warning"* This has nothing to do with presence or absence of PHP on your computer.

Comment: *"After that I decide download another PHP interpreter from php.net but I can not find any php.exe. It just c file."* You have downloaded sources then. All PHP downloads for Windows platform are located here: http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Overall -- it looks like there are some problems with your PhpStorm.I suggest to delete your IDE settings (back them up first, of course) and try starting from scratch. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs -- maybe some of the plugins you have there are doing something. Also try configuring new PHP Interpreter in new empty project.

Comment: Official Manuals/How-Tos: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: thank you so much. I will try those stuff with hope that i can pass and post the answer here after that. Now i must use netbean and not happy much :)).